# how can get odata from wcf servie and pass it to end user with web api

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a multi-tiered application with data and application layers.

If I need to use `odata`, I can implement it with `web-api` and user can pass parameters but how can `web-api` can talk to `wcf` service in this scenario?

Is it possible? Is there a standard solution? Is there a recommended solution from Microsoft?

I tried to search for a good reference, but I couldn't find any samples for how to use OData with web api and WCF together.

Comment: why do you need both Web API and WCF?

Comment: my software architecture is like this: first layer is data access layer, after that is my Business layer (WCF) and then my proxy layer (WCF) and then Client Layer (Web API) and then end user (Browsers, Native APP), So how can i use odata from data access to end user?

Comment: i want to get odata filters from enduser in web api and pass it to proxy layer then business and then business to data access for generate linq query, is it possible at all?